# Outputting new lines to txt files. (Python 3.2)

Tags: python, text

all. I'm having trouble outputting new lines to a txt file. The output is good but it's all in one line. Any ideas on how to work around?

```
#Double numberer
end=100
count=0

count=int(input("What number would you like to start?"))
end=int(input("What number would you like to end?"))
biglist = []

logfile=open("output.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8")

while count < end+1:
    logfile.write(str(count),"\n")
    logfile.write(str(count),"\n")
    print(count)
    count += 1


print("done")
logfile.close()
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, not on some other website. StackOverflow is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers; what happens when pastebin shuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanksshuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok cool. I had a hard time pasting while keeping the indentations in place.

Comment: @user596100, it's not too bad if you paste in all the code, select it all in the HTML editor widget, and hit the `{}` button in the toolbar. (I know, I usually ignore toolbars in HTML edit widgets, but this one is useful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate the new lines to the string, use a `+` symbol:

```
logfile.write(str(count) + "\n")
logfile.write(str(count) + "\n")
```

Also, be aware that your `while` loop incrementing `count` each time is unnecessary in Python. You could just do this:

```
for x in range(0, end + 1):
    logfile.write((str(x) + "\n") * 2)
    print(x)
```

Comment: However that isn't the appropriate way to handle newlines by adding `'\n'` manually.

Comment: @Kabie yeah, probably not, he should be adding `os.linesep`, but I won't nitpick

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is:

```
print(string, file=theFileYouOpened)
```